# Populate fields with third party API data in React-Admin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

We are using ReactAdmin to create some forms. One of these forms has the possibility of adding multiple addresses for a user. To build this form we use SimpleFormIterator (that is inside a SimpleForm). What I need to do is to update the address input fields with data from a third party API. I need to make 2 calls to the API, the first one to get addresses based on user input then get the address that the user has selected from the AutocompleteInput.

The first call works find and populates the AutocompleteInput, the second API call gets the data and updated the fields but ReactAdmin does not register the new values and the SAVE of the addresses does not containt the new values. Do you know why this is happening? Here are the steps that I did already:

1. Added AutocompleteInput that gets me what the users has inputed
2. Retrieved multiple addresses and populated the AutcompleteInput suggestions
3. Managed to get the data from the suggestion that the user has chosen

After getting the data I can populate the address fields using the *value* property. My problem is that the overall data that is managed by the SimpleForm from ReactAdmin does not get populated and is not being sent to the server. Has anyone tried this before?

You can see bellow a snippet of my code.

```
const UserCreate = (props) => {
    const [userAddresses, setUserAddresses] = useState({});
    const onUserAddressesChange = (data) => {
        setUserAddresses(data);
    };

    return (<Create {...props}>
        <SimpleForm
            submitOnEnter={false}
            redirect={redirect}>
            <AddressFields
                name='userAddresses'
                value={userAddresses}
                onAddressChange={onUserAddressesChange} />
        </SimpleForm>
    </Create>);
}

const AddressFields = (props) => {
    const { onAddressChange } = props;
    const [address, setAddress] = useState({
        city: '',
        addressLine1: '',
        addressLine2: '',
        addressLine3: '',
    });

    const onAddressIdChange = (addressId) => {
        dataProvider.getAddress(addressId)
            .then((result) => {
                const retrievedAddress = result.data[0];
                const newAddress = {
                    city: retrievedAddress.Field2,
                    addressLine1: retrievedAddress.Field3,
                    addressLine2: retrievedAddress.Field4,
                    addressLine3: retrievedAddress.Field5
                };
                
                setAddress( newAddress );
                onAddressChange( newAddress );
            });
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <ArrayInput source="userAddresses">
                <SimpleFormIterator>
                    <AddressLookupInput
                        onAddressIdChange={onAddressIdChange}>
                    </AddressLookupInput>
                    <AddressInputs address={address} />
                </SimpleFormIterator>
            </ArrayInput>
        </div>
    );
};

class AddressLookupInput extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.onFilterToQuery = this.onFilterToQuery.bind(this);
    }

    onFilterToQuery(searchText) {
        return { searchText };
    }

    render() {
        const { onAddressIdChange } = this.props;
        return (
            <ReferenceInput
                onChange={onAddressIdChange}
                source='addressesSource'
                reference='addressReference'
                label="Address lookup"
                filterToQuery={this.onFilterToQuery}>
                <AutocompleteInput
                    optionValue="id"
                    optionText="addressText"
                ></AutocompleteInput>
            </ReferenceInput>
        );
    }
}

const AddressInputs = ({ address, ...props }) => {
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <TextInput
                label="Address Line1"
                source="addressLine1"
                value={address.addressLine1} />
            <TextInput
                label="Address Line2"
                value={address.addressLine2}
                source="addressLine2" />
            <TextInput
                label="Address Line3"
                value={address.addressLine3}
                source="addressLine3" />
            <TextInput
                label="City"
                value={address.city}
                source="city" />
        </Fragment>
    );
};
```

Comment: The ReferenceInput component must have a reference to another resource via prop reference="dict_res"

Comment: I edited the code in stack overflow and I forgot to copy the reference prop. I had set it in my code and it still does not work.